# Default Value for Task<T> Property

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm trying to setup a cache something like the below; my problem is knowing what to set the initial value of the LoadingTask properties.

With the code below I get a warning on the MyCache constructor `Non-nullable field 'LoadingTask1' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable.`

I could declare LoadingTask1 as nullable, but then the `WhenAll` function complains...

I would like to do something like `public Task<MyObj1> LoadingTask1 = Task.Empty;`, but that doesn't exist.

I see I could do something like `= Task.CompletedTask`, but I assume that would look like the task is complete...  any ideas on how to do this - or is my approach flawed?

```
public class MyCache
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public IMemoryCache Cache { get; set; }

    public MyObj2? Data => LoadingTask2.IsCompletedSuccessfully ? LoadingTask2.Result : null;

    public Task<MyObj1> LoadingTask1;
    public Task<MyObj2> LoadingTask2;


    public MyCache(string key, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        Key = key;
        Cache = cache;
    }

    public async Task LoadData()
    {
        LoadingTask1 = ...;
        await LoadingTask1;

        LoadingTask2 = ...;
        await LoadingTask2;

        this.Save();
    }
}

public static class MyCacheExtensions
{
    public static MyCache GetData(this IMemoryCache cache, string key)
    {
        MyCache? myCache = cache.Get<MyCache>(key);
        if (myCache == null)
        {
            myCache = new(key, cache);
            myCache.Save();

            _ = myCache.LoadData();

            return myCache;
        }
        else
        {
            Task.WhenAll(myCache.LoadingTask1, myCache.LoadingTask2);
            return myCache;
        }
    }

    public static void Save(this MyCache myCache)
    {
        MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheItemPolicy = new()
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5)
        };
        myCache.Cache.Set(myCache.Key, myCache, cacheItemPolicy);
    }

    public static void Dispose(this MyCache myCache, string key)
    {
        myCache.Cache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your _Fields_ shouldn't be `public` in the first place. Just to begin with. Still reading.

Comment: It depends on the behavior you want. What should happen when someone awaits this default task?

Comment: Can you explain how you plan on that Cache to be used? I am struggling to discriminate internal functionality from public API.

Comment: You're correct, much of this needs to be made `private`; I expect the only way in is via the `GetData()` extension method - does that explain how it will be used?

Comment: No. It doesn't explain anything. How should the default tasks behave when awaited? Once you figure that out you can determine if any solutions are appropriate. For example, you could return a task which resolves to the default value for a given type although that's almost certainly a bad idea in most cases.

Comment: I wouldn't want to `await LoadingTask1`; so that behaviour is 'unexpected'; I would only go through `GetData()`, so when calling `Task.WhenAll(myCache.LoadingTask1, myCache.LoadingTask2);` they should look like started but incomplete tasks

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is caching you probably want to use [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-7.0)

```
private Lazy<Task<MyObj1>> LoadingTask1;

public MyCache(string key, IMemoryCache cache)
{
    ...
    LoadingTask1 = new Lazy<T>(CreateTask1);
}
public Task<MyObj1> CreateTask1(){...}

public async Task LoadData()
{
    await LoadingTask1.Value;
    ....
```

This would only start running the task after `LoadData` was run.

You can configure different threading options for Lazy if LoadData need to be thread safe. You could also just make your Task nullable, `Task<MyObj1>?`, but I would prefer the Lazy-option since it makes the intent clearer.

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is answer - I'm not familiar with `Lazy` (will read more); however, not sure how my WhenAll would look - and you've moved the task creation to the constructor, I really need it in the LoadData method - I will have multiple LoadData functions...

Comment: @BenRobinson the constructor only passes a *delegate* to the Lazy-object. The `CreateTask1` will only run the first time `LoadData` is called.  I can honestly not tell how you intend for the cache to work, but if you want to wait for both tasks, just do `Task.WhenAll(LoadingTask1.Value, LoadingTask2.Value)`.